# Track view visibility by percentage in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to get visibility percentage of the ExampleView. I tried below things which you can see in code. To more precise word when ExampleView become visible it's going start counting how many percent of that view is visible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        List {
            ForEach(1..<20) { index in
                
                if index%5 == 0 {
                    VStack {
                        ExampleView()
                            .onPreferenceChange(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                                print(value as Any)
                            }
    
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 500)
                }else {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(minHeight: 300)
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct BoundsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    typealias Value = Anchor<CGRect>?
    static var defaultValue: Value = nil

    static func reduce(
        value: inout Value,
        nextValue: () -> Value
       ) {
          value = nextValue()
      }
 }

struct ExampleView: View {

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.yellow
        Text("Hello World !!!")
            .anchorPreference(
                key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self,
                value: .bounds
            ) { $0 }
    }
    .overlayPreferenceValue(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            preferences.map {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke()
                    .frame(
                        width: geometry[$0].width,
                        height: geometry[$0].height
                    )
                    .offset(
                        x: geometry[$0].minX,
                        y: geometry[$0].minY
                    )
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

On overlayPreferenceValue(offset) calling every time when its frame of ExampleView is changing. However I don't how get those percentage. If you any other suggestion please let me know.

Please help me to get visibility percentage. Please let me know if you need more information about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here I found my answer. If you have any better solution or suggestion, Please comment on it or edit it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .frame(minHeight: 300)
            List {
                ForEach(1..<20) { index in
                    
                    if index%5 == 0 {
                        VStack {
                            CustomView()
                        }
                        .frame(minHeight: 300)
                    }else {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.blue)
                            .frame(minHeight: 300)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}

struct CustomView: View {

  var body: some View {
    Image("Monitor")
        .resizable()
        .background(Color.red)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.getPercentage(geo: geo, heightOfAdView: 300)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global)) { _ in
                        self.getPercentage(geo: geo, heightOfAdView: 300)
                    }
            }
        )
}

func getPercentage(geo: GeometryProxy,heightOfAdView: CGFloat) {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let yAxisOfAdView = geo.frame(in: .global).origin.y
    let visiblityInPx = screenHeight - yAxisOfAdView
    let visiblePCT = (visiblityInPx * 100.0)/heightOfAdView
    print("screenHeight:- \(screenHeight)")
    print("yAxisOfAdView:- \(yAxisOfAdView)")
    print("visiblityInPx:- \(visiblityInPx)")
    visiblePCT <= 100 ? print("visiblePCT:- \(visiblePCT)") :       print("visiblePCT:- 100")
  }
}
```

Comment: Bloody legend.. very nice!